# Wcf set integer values to default

Tags: c#, wcf

Here is my class :

```
 [DataContract]
public class UserRepo
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Picture { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int LoginCount { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my wcf function:

```
    public ReponseResult UpdateUser(UserRepo _userRepo)
    {
        try
        {
            var userDb = UserDB.GetInstance();
            var result = userDb.UpdateUser(_userRepo);

            var respReponseResult = new ReponseResult();
            respReponseResult.Message = "Success";
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            var returnObject = new ReturnObject()
            {
                ObjectName = "User Update",
                Result = new List<object>() { result, false }
            };


            string json = js.Serialize(returnObject);
            respReponseResult.Result = json;
            return respReponseResult;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

integer and bool props of UserRepo objects is 0 and false after I send it to wcf. Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you initializing the UserRepo class before calling the WCF function? Are you checking individual values in the UpdateUser method?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this situation in my project. In fact, when the proxy generates code from WSDL, each parameter will have an auto generated flag parameter e.g. if your field is `IsActive` then the autogenerated property will be `IsActiveSpecified`, see below.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
public System.bool IsActive{
    get {
        return this.isActiveField;
    }
    set {
        this.isActiveField= value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsActive");
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public bool IsActiveSpecified{
    get {
        return this.IsActiveSpecified;
    }
    set {
        this.IsActiveSpecified= value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsActiveSpecified");
    }
}
```

So you should set `IsActiveSpecified=true`, if not, the value transmitted is the default value.

Hope that resolve your problem